# ключевое слово new в java

Tags: java, new

Можно ли создавать объекты класса (с использованием ключевого слова new) вне оболочки метода main, например, в кастомном методе или вообще вне всяких методов, как те же глобальные переменные класса?

Comment: Конечно можно... Но правильней было бы сказать "Можно ли создавать **экземпляры** класса...".

Comment: Разумеется, это ключевое слово и существует для создания экземпляров объектов при инициализации полей, локальных и статических переменных.